# How to set the "CSRFprotect" parameter to prevent AJAX hijacking?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

In [This article](http://alexaitken.net/code/csrf-protection-via-x-browser-jquery-ajax-hijack.htm) the auther mentioned a way to protect from AJAX hijacking by using `CSRFprotect` param but I didn't understand how he set it's value ?

I would put the code here but when I do it appears inapprehensible .

Answer (score 0):

He's intercepted the [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) ajax events in order to add a custom querystring parameter (ie it's a custom solution, and would need to be implemented carefully on the server-side too, it's not a standard solutoin).  Would probably help against a general case website infection, but not against a targeted attack.

Comment: Do you have a better solution ?